# .NET Project - Android Sensory data

Tags: c#, android, .net, android-sensors

I was thinking about a project where a .Net C# application periodically retrieves or receives all sensory data from a Wifi connected Android device for logging purposes. There are several sensor apps for Android, so it must be possible.

Do any of you know of existing projects where sensory data is sent & used? Or do I have to start from scratch?

Kind regards, 
Tobias

Comment: My goal is to log & handle all sensor data in a PC .NET application from a wifi connected android device. The android apps that exist, log and handle sensor data but on the device itself, but I haven't found one that sends them to a PC/Cloud service. Sensors I'm talking about are accelerometer, magnetometer, thermometer, GPS, etc...

Comment: Found this http://harinadha.wordpress.com/category/android/, might be everything I need.